# How to use proration mode in app subscription android

Tags: java, android, in-app-subscription, google-pay, android-inapp-purchase

I using two subscription plans monthly and yearly in my android app.
If a user has subscribed monthly plan then I want to give the user an option to upgrade to a yearly plan. I have read an official document I need to use BillingFlowParams.ProrationMode but I am unable to figure out how should I implement this.

Here is the code sample:

```
BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
        .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
        .setOldSku(oldSku)
        // I need to replace replaceSkusProrationMode to DEFERRED
        // how do I get complete path to DEFERRED
        .setReplaceSkusProrationMode(replaceSkusProrationMode)
        .build()
int responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, flowParams);
```

using this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams.ProrationMode.html#DEFERRED) I get the int value for DEFERRED is 4 but it's not a good idea to use hardcoded value.

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an older version of billingclient upgrade to newer version solved my problem.

I changed to

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.2'
```

From

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'
```

then I get an option for setReplaceSkusProrationMode.

Here how I am using now:

```
BillingFlowParams flowParams1 = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                        .setOldSku(monthly_test)
                        .setReplaceSkusProrationMode(BillingFlowParams.ProrationMode.DEFERRED)
                        .setSkuDetails(yearly_test)
                        .build();
```