# How to handle if user purchased a Monthly Subscription and right after purchased a Yearly Subscription in FLutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

My app has `In App Purchased` enabled and two options

- Monthly Subscription
- Yearly Subscription

But **all have the same benefits**, **all enables premium version** of app.

How should I handle if this happen?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56949330

Comment: Refer this link you can set proration modes and to track which pack is purchased by user, in Android you will get all the information in queryPurchases and in iOS you will get that from appstore receipt path

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `https://www.revenuecat.com/` to reduce the boilerplate and very high complexity of building an in app purchase system yourself. There are a few good tutorials on `revenuecat` you can find on youtube. I use it myself I would its a great solution for sure.